# Should I implement my own caching or rely on read-replicas?

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, caching, redis

We have an enterprise application that uses an SQL database. The database access characteristics are about 90% reads. The data that does get updated or created needs to be up-to-date immediately. The cache needs to be correctly invalidated with high certainty. The entities are referred to by their primary key for 98% of the cases.

The application is based on Node.js and is AWS-native. Since the application is AWS-native, I'd like to rely on managed services from AWS rather than hosting my own. One option is to implement our read-through Redis-based cache. Upon retrieving the entities, we'd check the cache and if the data is not cached we'd put it into the cache before turning it to the user. The parts of the code that update those entities will invalidate the cache by primary key.

Generally speaking, in computer science cache coherency is one of the most challenging problems to get right. I am of the opinion that rather than implementing a Redis cache and thinking through all of the possible scenarios for correctly invalidating it, it is wiser to instead configure an Aurora read-replica specifically for reading frequently accessed entities. The RDBMS will do a much better job at caching than anything we can build ourselves.

So, I am facing two options -- go through the effort of implementing my own caching, or use read replicas. My personal opinion is to use a read replica.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, as always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you're right, cache invalidation is a tough problem. The simplest solution is to add code to your data writes, to replace the cached values. So they're always current. But this is easy only if the cached values have a pretty much 1-to-1 correlation with rows in your database.

An advantage of your own cache is that you can cache data that is *not* 1-to-1 with rows of data in the database. You might cache an entire HTML fragment for a drop-down menu for example. That could be the result of several SQL queries. It could be quite an advantage to cache data that is higher up the "food chain" so to speak. But cache invalidation becomes less straightforward. Best for storing results of queries that don't change often.

Using a read-replica is not a substitute for using a cache. Querying a read-replica still has overhead of making a database connection, authentication, SQL query parsing and optimization, locking, and all the other overhead that goes into RDBMS workings.

Querying data from a cache can be orders of magnitude faster.

Both have their place. It's best to use both a cache *and* a read-replica for different tasks. I would also add message queues as an important technology. I believe database, cache, and queue form a three-legged stool.

But you must have experience and judgment to know when each is the best tool for a given case.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head -- use cache for things that don't change often, and it is ok if an invalidation was somehow missed due to a bug or some other circumstance, and use read replicas for general purpose improvements in reading performance.